# How to handle this relationship scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am building an API where I have the following scenario:

**Companies** which has many **Projects** which has many **Tasks**. As a **User** I belong to a **Company** and I can create a **Task**.

*There are more similar scenarios in the system. All these entities but **User** have a int64 Id.*

This **task** creation payload would be something like:

```
{
    "summary": "summary",
    "description": "description",
    "projectId": 1
}
```

What's hammering my mind is: Should I validate if both the **Project** provided in the payload and the logged in **User** belong to the same **Company** before allowing the **Task** creation? I am afraid the wrong **projectId** is provided in the payload and then the **Task** would be created in a totally different **Project**, perhaps even of a different **Company**.

However, I feel like querying the database to validate stuff in each one of these similar scenarios (as mentioned above) would be too much and maybe there would be a lot more code. Is validating these scenarios really the "right" approach? What about using GUID as id for these entities and then only checking if the **Project** exists or not?

Comment: It really depends on your business use case. Do you need to verify the user before allowing them to create a task?

Comment: @Joe I was only going to verify if they're authenticated and check the companyId in their token or something like that as well as checking if their role is allowed to create a task

Comment: Depends on your use case.
Do you have a caching mechanism in place ?

Comment: No, I don't @AjayV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to create a secure system where users can't access projects or companies that they don't own? Then check all parameters.

Do you want to have a false sense of security and type maybe a little bit less code? Then use GUIDs and hope nobody guesses correctly and won't obtain valid (but not their) GUIDs.

Comment: Do you have any materials or suggestions about where the checking should happen? I'm using a controller -> service approach and currently I'm checking the payload within the service with FluentValidation but only simple checks such as min/max length, null, etc. and sometimes I check db to see if the field is unique